# Xceed Property Grid : Collection Editor Not Expanding In Proper Manner

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed, collectioneditor

I have used the Xceed Property Grid. I have used the Collection Editor from Xceed for Collections in this Property Grid.

```
[Editor(typeof(CustomCollectionEditor), typeof(CustomCollectionEditor))]
[Serializable]
public class Variable
{
//Properties in Class
}
```

Here the Custom Collection Editor has been derived from Xceed Collection Editor. But nothing has been overwritten. It is just a wrapper class.

The Xceed Website tells the following process to Expand:
"The PropertyGrid supports this scenario and allows you to drill down into a property’s heirarchy. To enable this behavior you must decorate your property with the ExpandableObject attribute"

So I have Used it in my Property as:

```
[ExpandableObject]
public List<Variable> GlobalVariableList
{
  get { return _varlist; }
  set { _varlist = value; }
}
```

But only the Count of the Properties are displayed in Expanding this. And not the Property Name and Value.

Comment: Property Name and Value are most probably only public fields, you need to make them into public properties, i.e. adding {get;set;} to their definition, so that they could be shown by Xceed property grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think your customcollectioneditor needs to be on the collection not the item.